# How to pass multiple delimiters into the $split pipeline function in mongodb query?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to split the string based on multiple delimiters namely comma,space and dot.
How can I pass this to the $split function?

I tried " |.|," in the second argument, but it did not work.

Sample collection structure:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "i like product 1",

  },
   {
    "foo": "product 3, is bad",

  },
]
```

//Query that I tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      words: {
        $split: [
          "$foo",
          " |.|,"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$words"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$words",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass regex as a delimiter in $split. Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/.

If 'foo' follows English rules i.e. space would be followed by a comma and full-stop then the following query would work for you. We are splitting the words on white space and them trimming out comma and full-stop from each word.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "words":{
                $split:["$foo"," "]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "words":{
                $map:{
                    "input":"$words",
                    "as":"word",
                    "in":{
                        $trim:{
                            "input": "$$word",
                            "chars": " .,"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$words"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$words",
            "word":{
                $first:"$words"
            },
            "count":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Result:

```
{ "word" : "bad", "count" : 1 }
{ "word" : "is", "count" : 1 }
{ "word" : "i", "count" : 1 }
{ "word" : "product", "count" : 2 }
{ "word" : "like", "count" : 1 }
{ "word" : "3", "count" : 1 }
{ "word" : "1", "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes , the corner case when dot is not followed by space fails.But I have got a start now